# Show element on hover another using css

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm working on a tiny css action which based on A element hover, will display another element. The code is pretty basic:

```
<a title="#" class="portfolio-reaction" href="#">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/OZb7SI8.png" class="attachment-grid-feat" />
<div class="headline-overlay">LOREM IPSUM</div>
</a>

.portfolio-reaction {
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  display:block;
}

.headline-overlay {
    background:none;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    z-index:999;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:0.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.3em;
    color:#000;
}
.attachment-grid-feat:hover ~ .headline-overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

and jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yL231zsk/1/

This solution works in 99%. The missing percent is the effect - while moving mouse arrow through the button, text is blinking. I have no idea why. Secondly - what if I want to extend number of appearing elements from 1 to 3. So to have:

```
<a title="#" class="portfolio-reaction" href="#">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/OZb7SI8.png" class="attachment-grid-feat" />
<div class="headline-overlay">
  <p class="element-1">abc</p>
  <p class="element-2">111</p>
  <div class="element-3">X</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Thank you for any tips and advices.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the three elements (element-1, element-2, element-3) to appear on hover at the same time ?

Comment: exactly - this is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote the following in your css file :

```
.attachment-grid-feat:hover ~ .headline-overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

It won't work since `.attachment-grid-feat` isn't the parent of `.headline-overlay`. So it won't select the state when the parent is selected because there are no element `.healine-overlay` inside `.attachment-grid-feat`. Also no need to add `~` between the two. The right selector is the following :

```
.portfolio-reaction:hover .headline-overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

This way you are targeting the child div `.healine-overlay` when parent div `.portfolio-reaction` (you might want to make the `<a>` tag a `<div>` tag) is hovered.

```css
.portfolio-reaction {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
}

.headline-overlay {
  background: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #000;
}

.portfolio-reaction:hover .headline-overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div title="#" class="portfolio-reaction" href="#">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OZb7SI8.png" class="attachment-grid-feat" />
  <div class="headline-overlay">
    <div id="element-1">Hello 1</div>
    <div id="element-2">Hello 2</div>
    <div id="element-3">Hello 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this code snippet, three elements are contained inside `.headline-overlay`. On hover, all three elements are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

First, change the last CSS line from this:

```
.attachment-grid-feat:hover ~ .headline-overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

into this:

```
.attachment-grid-feat:hover .headline-overlay {
    display:block;
}
```

And will "half" work. You need after to change the `width` and `height` of your `<div class="headline-overlay">` from a smaller percentage to match your square width and height(leaving it to 100% covers the entire screen, and as a result, the text wont dissapear, no matter where you will move the cursor). Or, If you want your `<div>` element to match automaticaly the square size, then you leave the width and height unchanged and change only his `position:absolute` into `position:relative` and of course, a little adjusting his position from `top`.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yL231zsk/9/